# Fixed point of a functor

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors, fixed-points

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cocomplete category, and let $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ be a functor with a natural transformation $i:1_\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow F$. If we have an object $c\in\mathcal{C}$, then we have a diagram
$$c\xrightarrow{i_c}F(c)\xrightarrow{i_{F(c)}}F^2(c)\xrightarrow{i_{F^2(c)}}\cdots$$
of which we can take the colimit $\widehat{c}:=\operatorname{colim}_nF^n(c)$. Is it true that $\widehat{c}$ is a fixed point for $F$, i.e. that $i_{\widehat{c}}:\widehat{c}\to F(\widehat{c})$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$?

---

This is not true in general, as pointed out by @Roland in the comments. What assumptions do we have to make on $F$ and $i$ in order for $\widehat{c}$ to be a fixed point?

(Of course, it is true if $i$ is a natural isomorphism, and it should also be true if $F$ commutes with colimits. I would like weaker conditions, if possible.)

Comment: Seems like you need $F$ to be colimit-preserving for this to be true.  Is your $F$ left adjoint for another?

Comment: @Randall Yes, if $F$ preserves colimits then it works. Unfortunately, the specific $F$ I want to consider isn't left adjoint that I know of.

Comment: In that case, I wish you luck :)

Comment: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of sets and $F(c)$ be the underlying set of the free group spanned by $c$. Then $c\rightarrow F(c)$ is never an isomorphism.

Comment: See Adamek's theorem (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fixed+point), which is closely related. You only need $F$ to commute with directed colimits, which is easier.

Comment: @Roland don't we have $c \cong F(c)$ whenever c is infinite (and assuming choice)? Or am I not understanding your terminology?

Comment: @JasonCarr The sets have the same cardinality, but the natural transformation (which is part of the data of the problem) is not a bijection.

Comment: @QuiaochuYuan Thanks. It doesn't gove me what I hoped for, but it's something.